# Overcoming the effect of Limerence?

Tags: social-psychology

I recently came to know about  [Limerence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limerence).

I could not find definite answers for the following questions:

1. It has been said that limerence generally lasts between 18 months to
   3 years, could be more in some cases. Is there a
   way/approach/strategy to reduce this duration?
2. As per this [article](http://www.uncommonforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=48554), it has been suggested that limerence is
   due to low self esteem. This conclusion was based on "I never
   expected anything in return". I thought this is what most successful
   people like Bill Gates, Clinton do with their charity/foundation
   without expecting anything in return. How can this be judged as a bad thing?
   Is Limerence really due to low self esteem?
3. I have read that limerence can affect people's mind at a
   unconscious level. Is there a way to train the unconscious mind to
   get rid of the limerence effect?
4. I could not find anyone offering therapy specifically for this.
   Has therapy been shown to help conditions like this?
5. It has been mentioned in the Wikipedia article that people with
   limerence can become ill. If you are ill, is there a way to find out if this is caused by limerence or something else?

See also:

- [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1445186)
- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/cgot5/askreddit_how_do_i_make_myself_fall_out_of_love/)

Comment: @Knight: first time I heard of it too, interesting to see that high rate of coincidence between limerence, depersonalization/derealization disorder.....I wonder what the difference is between girls in High School in love with every "cute" guy vs. this.

Comment: @GregMcNulty - it's very interesting how Limerence is related to other things. The more I try to understand the human mind the more complicated it gets. I'm glad to find there is a reason for every behaviour.

Comment: Checked depersonalization, it sounds a lot like the typical experience of a dreamer within a dream.

Comment: @Knight: perhaps we should understand more what is going on in depersonalization to understand this ?

Comment: This has five questions in one. Could you please restate them as individual questions? It's not very possible to answer them all coherently within the same post.